# How to make volumetric fog darker in the compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, image, volumetrics

So I rendered this glacier scene in layers and I am trying make the volumetric fog darker. However, whenever I try to make the fog darker (i.e. with either the color ramp, color balance, RGB curves, etc), it just decreases the fog. The same goes for whenever I try to change the blend mode (i.e. multiply, mix, add, subtract, etc) for the mix shader that the fog is connected to. Whenever I try and make the color darker, it just decreases the fog. And whenever I try to increase the amount of fog (like, for example, with the color ramp), it'll increase the amount of fog, but it also makes my scene waaaaaay too bright, which is not what I want.

I want the same amount of fog, just darker.

Is there any way to make volumetric fog darker (or at least the illusion that it is darker) while maintaining the amount of fog in the compositor???

Here is a copy of the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/0gb98uxxeh6h52pi15wt9/h?dl=0&rlkey=kjipjlnhbk5pe1eep2oodsnxc). down below is a screenshot of my node set up and an image of the compositor view of my scene.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your fog a separate pass ?

Comment: @Emir it is a separate pass